# jQuery Extend Function

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between `$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype, {` and `$.extend($.ui.dialog, {`?

Answer (score 3):

The first one adds properties to the prototype of the "dialog" function, while the second adds properties to the "dialog" function object itself. The effect of the first one is to extend the "capabilities" of all instances of objects constructed through that function ("$.ui.dialog").  The second just adds properties to the function object itself, presumably constants or utility methods.